# How to query other tables in ARRAY_AGG rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, array-agg

I have the below tables:

- team

  | col_name | type |
  | --- | --- |
  | id | string |
  | name | string |
  | coach_id | string |
- player

  | col_name | type |
  | --- | --- |
  | id | string |
  | name | string |
  | team_id | string |
  | main_skill_id | string |
- coach

  | col_name | type |
  | --- | --- |
  | id | string |
  | name | string |
- skill

  | col_name | type |
  | --- | --- |
  | id | string |
  | name | string |

I'm using the below query in PostgreSQL to retrieve all the `team`'s `player`s, along with the `team` itself and the `coach`:

```sql
SELECT
  "team".*,
( SELECT coach FROM "coach" WHERE "coach"."id" = "team".coach_id ) AS coach,
( SELECT ARRAY_AGG ( player ) FROM "player" WHERE "player".team_id = "team"."id" ) AS players,
FROM
    "team"
WHERE
    "team"."id" = '123'
```

This is working amazing!

But now I need to query the `main_skill` of the `player` for those players in `ARRAY_AGG`.

**How to do that?**

This is an SQL query I'm generating in my backend based on possibly asked graphql fields.

The actual result is:

| id | name | coach_id | coach | players |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | The good ones | 1 | {1,"Bob"} | {"(1,"John",1,1)","(2,"Tom",1,2)"} |

The result I need is:

| id | name | coach_id | coach | players |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | The good ones | 1 | {1,"Bob"} | {"(1,"John",1,1,{main_skill:{1,"MainSkill1Name"}})","(2,"Tom",1,2,{main_skill:{2,"MainSkill2Name"}})"} |

Comment: Update your post with sample data (in tabular format) and expected output. That will allow readers to fully understand what you're looking for.

Comment: In the first part of your post, are those table definitions? There is no player field in player table.

Comment: @PepeNO, you're right. I updated the question and now I'm updating it better.

Comment: @lemon, the question is complete now I think. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need **a json object inside `players` array column** you can use this query:

```
with player_data as (
  select player.id as player_id,
       player.name as player_name,
       player.team_id as player_team_id,
       player.main_skill_id as player_skill_id,
       json_build_object('main_skill', array[skill.id, skill.name]) as skill_json
  from player
  join skill on player.main_skill_id = skill.id)
select team.*,
       (select coach from coach where coach.id = team.coach_id) as coach,
       (select ARRAY_AGG(player_data) from player_data where player_data.player_team_id = team.id) as players
from team
where team.id = '1';
```

**Details:**

- The additional query builds a json object using `json_build_object()` function, and returns all the necessary in a `player_data` table:

```
  select player.id as player_id,
       player.name as player_name,
       player.team_id as player_team_id,
       player.main_skill_id as player_skill_id,
       json_build_object('main_skill', array[skill.id, skill.name]) as skill_json
  from player
  join skill on player.main_skill_id = skill.id
```

- Then `player_data` results are aggregated into one array in the outer query.

See the [**demo**](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3z8cz23pp).

Answer (score 1):

Just create a matrix for your required fields (all of player and all of skill tables) like this:

```
(select array_agg(array[p.id, p.name, p.team_id, p.main_skill_id, s.id, s.name]) 
from player p inner join
skill s on p.main_skill_id = s.id
where p.team_id = team.id)
```

The complete query would be like

```
SELECT
  team.*,
( SELECT coach FROM coach WHERE coach.id = team.coach_id ) AS coach,
( SELECT ARRAY_AGG ( array[p.id,p."name",p.team_id,p.main_skill_id,s.id,s."name"]  ) 
  FROM player p inner join skill s on  p.main_skill_id = s.id 
  WHERE p.team_id = team.id ) AS players
FROM
    team
WHERE
    team.id = '1';
```

[Working sample here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6jctKEu3Vp1qyDMPqSjscT/0)

Comment: Can you please re-read my question that I think is complete now?

Comment: Solution completed according to your question edits.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the `inner join`?

Comment: No because it establish a relationship between the two tables, however if the relationship between them is 1:1, is redundant have two tables when all fields can be in one (a reason for having two tables with a rel 1:1  would be a table that contains a large number of columns and you want to split it into two tables for performance reasons).